# Fecha de inicio y finalización siempre dá mi hora local en lugar de la fecha seleccionada en Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

Estoy implementando fullcalendar con Laravel, al momento de hacer click en cualquier día del calendario me arroja la hora local, da igual el día que seleccione, ejemplo (si doy click en el día 31 de diciembre me muestra la fecha de hoy que seria el 30).

Ya implementé los archivos (fullcalendar, moment, jquery, etc.) localmente y por cdn por si ese era el error pero nada, también estuve viendo videos pero lo único que encontré fue que pudiera estar formateando mal la hora de inicio.

El código es el siguiente:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h3 class="text-center mt-5">FullCalendar con Laravel</h3>
            <div class="col-md-11 offset-1 mt-5 mb-5">

                <div id="calendar">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="eventoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Guardar cita</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
          <span id="titleError" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script src="vendor/js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="vendor/js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.0.2/index.global.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                aspectRatio: 2,
                // slotMin: 'dayGridMonth',
                events:@json($eventos),
                selectable: true,
                headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                
                select: function(start, end, allDays) {

                    $('#eventoModal').modal('toggle');

                    $('#saveBtn').click(function() {

                        console.log(end_date);

                        $.ajax({
                            url:"{{ route('eventos.store') }}",
                            type:"POST",
                            dataType:'json',
                            data:{ evento, start_date, end_date  },
                            success:function(response)
                            {
                                $('#eventoModal').modal('hide')
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                    'title': response.title,
                                    'start' : response.start,
                                    'end'  : response.end,
                                    'color' : response.color
                                });

                            },
                            error:function(error)
                            {
                                if(error.responseJSON.errors) {
                                    $('#titleError').html(error.responseJSON.errors.title);
                                }
                            },
                        });
                    });
                }   
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
```

Al checar en consola el resultado me sigue dando la fecha actual

[image: Este es el resultado de presionar cualquier dia del mes]